# Javascript Sprite Animation Library for Canvas Tag

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, sprite

Can you point me to a good Javascript sprite animation library using the HTML Canvas tag?

A few Google searches only turned up some non-canvas projects.  I am looking for something clean and simple.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this comparison table — https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqj_mVmuz3Y8dHNhUVFDYlRaaXlyX0xYSTVnalV5ZlE#gid=0

Answer (score 9):

[Processing](http://www.processing.org/) is a great visualization / animation framework, who has been recently ported to JavaScript: http://ejohn.org/blog/processingjs/.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: The Processing JavaScript port is now officially hosted at http://processingjs.org

Answer (score 5):

There is the [cake](http://glimr.rubyforge.org/cake/canvas.html) toolkit as well, although it does provide different functionality (more closely sprite oriented) than processing.js (see @SebaGR's answer).

Unfortunately i don't think either of these libraries really constitutes a sprite library in a useful/complete way.

Answer (score 3):

you could look at create.js... it uses sprite sheets and is developed for the canvas tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good list of some javascript game engines:

http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/f094j/list_of_js_game_engines_community_effort/

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be better: http://www.c3dl.org/